# how to build wcf notification service

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf, notifications

I have this situation:
I have some wcf services which do stuffs, and have wcf RegistryService which enables me to get data about people, addresses etc.
The client application is a silverlight 4 application.
I want this:

that every time a client application updates a Registry (a person or an address) the service sends a change notification to all connected clients that the registry has changed.

how to do that?
thanks.

Comment: I believe you're looking for [wsDualHttpbinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding.aspx)